# Metric for ranked keyword identification

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

I am trying to determine which metric(s) to use to evaluate the "coverage" of a lexicon (list of words) with respect to a ranked list of significant keywords I have extracted from two different collections of texts. The two lists do not have any terms common. Importantly, only the top-n ranking words are to be considered "correct", while the bottom-m ranked words are to be considered "incorrect".

Below is a dummy example with a ranked keyword list and 4 different lexicons which each contain some of the words in the list.

```
rank  keyword    lexicon_1  lexicon_2  lexicon_3  lexicon_4
1     apple      False      True       True       False
2     orange     False      True       True       False
3     banana     False      False      True       False
4     pear       False      False      True       False
5     kiwifruit  True       False      True       False
6     watermelon True       False      True       False
-----------------------------------------------------------
7     car        False      False      False      True
8     bus        False      False      False      True
9     truck      True       False      False      True
10    bike       False      True       False      True
```

So the intuition is that the more high-ranking keywords (1-6) are included in a lexicon the better, and the fewer lower ranking keywords (7-10) are included the better.

Calculating precision (P), recall (R) and F-score (F) is one way of quantifying and comparing the coverage. For this, true positives (TP) are when the lexicon includes a correct word, false positives (FP) when it includes an incorrect word, true negatives (TN) when it excludes an incorrect word and false negatives (FN) when it excludes a correct word. With this in mind, for `lexicon_1`, for example, this gives:

```
TP=2, FP=1, TN=3, FN=4
P = 2 / (2 + 1)    R = 2 / (2 + 4)    F = 2 * 0.67 * 0.33 / (0.67 + 0.33)
  = 0.67             = 0.33             = 0.44
```

For `lexicon_2` we also get `F=0.44`. For `lexicon_3` we get `F=1.00` and for `lexicon_4` we get `F=0` (as undefined). So we can see that lexicons `1` and `2` are situated between `3` (best) and `4` (worst), but this does not take into account the fact that `lexicon_2` has more highly ranked words than `lexicon_1` and should therefore receive a more favourable evaluation.

Is there any metric that would take into account the ranking of words in these cases? I am aware of `average precision` and `mean average precision`, which account for ranking of retrieved results, but I'm not sure if those metrics are appropriate for this situation.

**EDIT 1:**

I have implemented my understanding of [average precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Average_precision) for this situation:

```py
def avep(df, lexicon_names):
    """
    Calculate average precision for each lexicon from 
    pre-calculated precision and recall scores stored
    in a DataFrame.
    """
    aveps = {}
    for l in lexicon_names:
        ap = 0.0
        for i in range(len(df)):
            p_i = df.iloc[i]['p_' + l]
            if i > 0:
                dr_i = df.iloc[i]['r_' + l] - df.iloc[i - 1]['r_' + l]
            else:
                dr_i = 0.0
            ap += p_i * dr_i
        aveps[l] = ap
    return aveps
```

This gives me the following results:

```
Lexicon     p                   r                   f                   AP                  
-------     -                   -                   -                   --                  
lexicon_1 : 0.6666666666666666  0.2857142857142857  0.4                 0.2857142857142857  
lexicon_2 : 0.6666666666666666  0.2857142857142857  0.4                 0.14285714285714285 
lexicon_3 : 1.0                 1.0                 1.0                 0.8571428571428571  
lexicon_4 : 0.0                 0.0                 0.0                 0.0
```

But this gives a better result for `lexicon_1` than `lexicon_2` which is the opposite of what I want (and AP is suspiciously equal to recall for `lexicon_1` and `2 x recall` for `lexicon_2`). Also, not sure what to do with the first row where difference in recall is undefined (using 0). This yields a value less than 1.0 for the "perfect" `lexicon_3`.

Any better suggestions would be much appreciated!

**EDIT 2:**

Here is my Python implementation of the solution provided by RobertBaron:

```py
def coverage_metric(df, lexicon_names):
    scores = {}

    max_score = int(''.join([str(x) for x in df.index]))

    for l in lexicon_names:
        correct_score = int(''.join([str(x) for x in df.loc[df[l] == True].index]))
        incorrect_score = int(''.join([str(x) for x in df.loc[df[l] == False].index]))
        scores[l] = (correct_score - incorrect_score) / max_score

    scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    return scores
```

This is the implementation of the number conversion required for RobertBaron's solution (as far as I understand it):

```py
def int2base(n, b):
    """
    Implementation of the algorith; described at http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html
    """
    x = ''
    while n > 0:
        d = int(n / b)
        r = n % b
        x += str(r)
        n = d

    return int(x)
```

Comment: Right now, you give all words the same weight of 1. Couldn't you assign each word a weight based on its rank?

Comment: @RobertBaron I've looked at that sort of thing but can't figure out a way to aggregate ranks in a uniform way without there being some kind of weird behaviour, e.g. single top rank keyword scoring higher than multiple lower ones, which doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a metric. There are n + m ranks. So, assign a digit from numbers in base n + m + 1 to each keyword, giving the highest-rank keyword the largest digit. In your example, we have 10 keywords, so digits are from base 11 and go from A to 1 (using hexadecimal digits) as shown below.

```
rank  digit  keyword    lexicon_1  lexicon_2  lexicon_3  lexicon_4
1     A      apple      False      True       True       False
2     9      orange     False      True       True       False
3     8      banana     False      False      True       False
4     7      pear       False      False      True       False
5     6      kiwifruit  True       False      True       False
6     5      watermelon True       False      True       False
------------------------------------------------------------------
7     4      car        False      False      False      True
8     3      bus        False      False      False      True
9     2      truck      True       False      False      True
10    1      bike       False      True       False      True
```

For each lexicon, the coverage metric is calculated as follows. For the correct keywords, starting from the highest rank, build a number by concatenating the digits of the keywords that are in the lexicon. For example, for our 4 lexicons, we have respectively `65`, `A9`, `A98765`, and `0`. Do the same thing for the incorrect keywords. This gives us `2`, `1`, `0`, and `4321`. The final metric is obtained by subtracting the two numbers built for each lexicon, that is, `65` - `1` = `64`, `A9` - `1` = `A8`, `A98765` - `0` = `A98765`, and `0` - `4321` = `-4321`.

If you want a metric in the range `[0 1]`, you can divide by `A98765` which is the maximum value that a lexicon can have in this example.

For convenience, base n + m + 1 numbers can be converted to base 10 for calculations. See [Number Conversion Algorithms](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html).

In our example which is base 11, for lexicon 1, we need to convert `65`, `1`, and `A98765` to base 10. We have:

6 x 11<sup>1</sup> + 5 x 11<sup>0</sup> = 71

1 x 11<sup>0</sup> = 1

10 x 11<sup>5</sup> + 9 x 11<sup>4</sup> + 8 x 11<sup>3</sup> + 7 x 11<sup>2</sup> + 6 x 11<sup>1</sup> + 5 x 11<sup>0</sup> = 1753845

And the metric for lexicon 1 is (71 - 1) / 1753845 = 0.000039912307

There is small mistake in the example. Because we can have negative values, the range of possible values goes from `-4321` to `A98765`. So, to get a metric in `[0 1]`, we need to shift by `4321` and divide by `A98765` + `4321`.

Comment: Thanks! This is very interesting, but I'm not sure I understand how it works, especially the reason for using of hexadecimal. Do you have a reference to a research paper for this?

Comment: Hi thanks. I have tried to implement this, but as my n and m are large (in the thousands) I get results that are not useful (e.g. -0.0 for all lexicons when I divide to obtain a result in [0 1] as you suggest). Should this work? I'll paste my code in my original post.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You are correct. What I don't understand is the base conversion from integers is base 10 to digits in base n + m + 1. If n + m + 1 is always greater than the maximum integer to be converted then aren't these integers not converted at all? That is the result I am getting at least, so probably haven't understood. I implemented the conversion algorithm on the page you linked to and will post it in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks. If my values are n=2162 and m=1220. So how do I go about converting from 'rank' to 'digit'? I need n + m + 1 digits. Is that right? How do I manage that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand (we seem to be talking at cross purposes here!). You say "do not convert to base 10", but that is not the issue I'm having - that is a later step. The problem is that I don't know how to get to base n + m + 1 in the first place. Where do my n + m + 1 digits come from?

Comment: Yes, I get that. But then how do I avoid having "digits" such as 112, 113, 114 etc. as you mentioned above? Hexadecimal uses letters for values 10-16. But I need over 3000 "digits", so what do I do? Sorry about this and I really appreciate your efforts in helping me understand this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196067/discussion-between-ongenz-and-robertbaron).